# Does Pellet reason over the Property Reification vocabulary?

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, pellet

I have been struggling with adding property reification to my owl ontologies and I came across a proposal in the W3 wiki for [Property Reification](http://www.w3.org/wiki/PropertyReificationVocabulary). I was wondering if Pellet (or any reasoner for that matter) is able to understand the vocabulary and reason over it, both natively and through SWRL rules. The proposed vocabulary is located [here](http://smiy.sourceforge.net/prv/spec/propertyreification.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the spec is only a draft at the moment. I'm not aware of any reasoner supporting it.